# checking mysql error code to prevent deleting a parent key to a foreign key to alert user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named magazine, there is a foreign key from a table called researcher.
I need to alert the user when they delete a researcher who has a magazine.
I did that by using the mysql error code.  this is my code.

```
elseif($_POST['submit'] == 'deleteresearcher'){
    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `researcher` where id = $researcherid");
    $stmt->execute();
     // after executing the statement, check if there's an error.  
    if (mysqli_errno($conn) ==1051){ 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sorry, can't delete researcher.');</script>";
      }
     // adding action 
    header("Location: admin_researcher.php?action=delete");    
}
```

P.S: the variable `$conn` is from the php file that connects with the database

Comment: Your SQL is insecure. You should not have `$researcherid` in SQL. Parameterize it and bind it. I'm unclear what your question/issue is.

Comment: ... and what do you get?

Comment: @hd1 doesn't alert me.  I get a page that says localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: You need to set the `header()` before ANY `echo` or output!

Comment: You should also enable `error_reporting(1);` in your PHP on the Development environment, to actually see any PHP errors... Basic troubleshooting.. or of course `tail` the error log..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `header()` before ANY `echo` or other output, even before this `elseif` condition.

You should also enable `error_reporting(1);` in your PHP on the Development environment, to actually see any PHP errors... Basic troubleshooting.. or of course `tail` the error log.

I do not want to comment the usage of JS's `alert()`

Comment: I enabled the error repoerting, and now this is what I get instead of an alert                  
 Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: There you go.. you now know of an error for which you are not checking :) Improve your code :) I do not think that you should actually be checking for each error code, you could simply be pulling the actual mysql error.. unless you want to show custom messages

Comment: @WafaAlOmar Wait `PDOException`?? You have `mysqli_errno`, what driver are you using????

Comment: Thank you for answering, Ron.  It worked now.  But why you don't want to comment the usage of JS's alert()? I am a beginner so please bear with me if you think my code is inefficient.  Thanks again.